# Following jQuery's - $.get data object and the URL Encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, urlencode

I was trying to follow along in the latest 1.9.* code for jQuery - looking for the area where it handles parsing the data parameter from $.get (get's 2nd argument). I'm getting lost somewhere. Where does this get turned into a URL with the correctly encoded parameters?

Comment: Could you add the part of the source you are talking about to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get()` is just a shotcut for `$.ajax()`. There you find

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
}
```

And in `jQuery.param`:

```
s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
```